# How to add class to block under position: sticky

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a block with position: sticky and a block under it. Is there any way to track the moment when the sticky block sticks to the top and add a class to the bottom block?

[image]

I think I should use $(window).scroll() but don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "official" way of telling an element is being stuck with sticky positioning as I know of right now. But you could use a [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

It works by observing changes in an elements position related for example to a viewport, in the case of this code sample it checks for at least a 1px difference (threshold: 1).

```
const el = document.querySelector(".stickyElement")
const observer = new IntersectionObserver( 
  ([e]) => document.querySelector(".elementThatShouldUpdate").classList.toggle("desired-class", e.intersectionRatio < 1),
  { threshold: [1] }
);

observer.observe(el);
```

You should also update your CSS for the sticky element to account for the 1px difference:

```
top: -1px;
```

And also account for this extra offset, so you should add either a border or a padding to this element:

```
padding-top: 1px;
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: you need to add 1px padding or border for the -1px;

Comment: @Anirudhsanthosh True, I will update the answer, thanks for pointing it out, might not be obvious :)

Comment: very nice of you